# Linux font viewer

Tags: linux, font-utility, font

What do you recommend to use for viewing fonts including the glyph, extras, and others in Linux? I need to see the Unicode for the glyph and special characters.

Answer (score 4):

How about [GNOME Character Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Character_Map) (`gucharmap`)? It shows information on every Unicode character and allows you to choose the font for glyph display.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try FontForge? Besides of making fonts, FontForge can also display preview of any fonts you have installed. It's free and available on Windows & Linux